# The TextBox in Material-UI doesn't recognize a new line ASCII code across browsers

Tags: textbox, material-ui, word-wrap

I have provided an example below that can be used on Chrome and Safari.

The placeholder on the multiline textbox doesn't use the `\n` parameter and instead shows it all on one line on Safari, and 3 lines as Chrome.

https://codesandbox.io/s/error-ssixg

I was wondering if there was a solution to get it to recognize on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiline string if you want to make sure the newline character works on all devices. Replace:

```js
`{\n      "Foo":"bar" \n}`
```

with

```js
`{
      "Foo":"bar"
}`
```